# How to run .sh file using hot corners

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

I am using Linux mint 19.2 and trying to assign the upper-left hot corner to run a shutdown command but sometimes I accidentally put my cursor into that corner so I decided to make a .sh file to ask for confirmation first but I can't run this .sh file using the hot corners.

I have already tried using `bash -c "/home/user/.shutdown.sh"` and `/home/user/.shutdown.sh` but it still won't work eventhough it works when i run it in terminal.

Here is my code in my .shutdown.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while : ; do
    read -n1 -r -p "Are you sure you want to quit? [Y/N] " key
    printf "\n"
    [[ $key != $'N' ]] || break
    [[ $key != $'n' ]] || break
    [[ $key != $'Y' ]] || shutdown -P now
    [[ $key != $'y' ]] || shutdown -P now
done
```

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Alt + t` + `shutdown -h now`. That takes me a second. If you want to use the mouse, why not using the shutdown button from your desktop environment? This comes with a confirmation dialog

Comment: Take a look at [Zenity - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity)